# How to find file extension change with node.js?

Tags: node.js

How do you detect a file extension change and save the new extension or full file path to a variable? This is a unique specific question.

Code I have so far dont mind if you dont use it:

```
const puppeteer = require('C:/Users/user1/Desktop/puppeteer_automation/node_modules/puppeteer');
(async () => {

    var filename = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/file.crdownload";
    var downloadanduploadpath = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads";
    var fs = require('fs');
    var event1 = "change";
    var currentstat = fs.stat();
    
    const WATCH_TARGET = filename;
    
    
    fs.watch(WATCH_TARGET, function(event1, downloadanduploadpath) {
         console.log('File "' + filename + '" was changed: ' + eventType);
       });
    
        
    /*
    fs.watch(downloadanduploadpath,  (event1, filename) => {
        console.log('event is: ' + event1);
        if (filename) {
            console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
        } else {
            console.log('filename not provided');
        }
    });*/

    
    //console.log(lastdownloadedimage);


})();
```

Error:

> (node:9876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError
> [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received
> undefined

Comment: What's the problem you have with the code you show?  When I try code just like you show on either a directory or an existing file, it works just fine for me on Windows.  When the file is renamed, I get a rename event.  FYI, you can't put a result from this callback into a variable and use it later.  Instead, you need to use it from within the callback.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. Getting error. "(node:9876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener),

> The listener callback gets two arguments (eventType, filename). eventType is either '**rename**' or 'change', and filename is the name of the file which triggered the event.

you can use the `eventType` argument to determine whether the filename has been changed.

---

**UPDATE**: I updated my example code to observe the directory instead of the file itself, in order to get the new filename in the `filename` argument

Example:

```js
let fs = require('fs');

(async () => {

    const WATCH_DIR = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads";
    let target_file = "file.crdownload";
    let renameTriggered = false;
    
    fs.watch(WATCH_DIR, function(eventType, filename) {
        if(eventType == 'rename') {
            // Check if the target filename was changed (in the first event 
            // the old filename disappears, which marks the beginning of a renaming process)
            if(filename == target_file) {
                // Toggle renaming status
                renameTriggered = true;
            }
            // The second event captures the new filename, which completes the process
            else if(renameTriggered) {
                // Toggle renaming status
                renameTriggered = false;
                console.log('File "' + target_file + '" was renamed to: "' + filename + '"');
                // Update target filename
                target_file = filename;
            }
        }
    });

})();
```

Observing the directory however will trigger the callback on any filename changes that occur (includes even deleting and creating files). Therefore we check if the `eventType` is equal to `'rename'`.

From the perspective of `fs.watch()` the renaming takes place in two steps: In the fisrt step the 'disappearing' of the old filename is detected which triggers the event passing the old filename as the argument `filename`. In the second step the 'appearance' of the new filename is detected which triggers the `rename` event again, this time with the new filename as the second argument, which is what we are looking for.

Comment: Thank You. How can I wait until the file changes? before continuing

Comment: Well, this is kind of another topic and it depends on how the rest of your application is works. I can't answer this unless you show us the rest of the code. But as I said, this is another topic. And the whole point of using `async` is not to wait.

Comment: @RobomanRobo I updated my example code again to account for the two steps the renaming process takes. If your question was answered please accept one of the answers to let other people know that your problem was solved and how.

Comment: Why is your outer function `async`?  There does not appear to be any reason for that.  There is no use of promises or `await`.

Comment: @jfriend00, because it was in the example code provided by the TO and i didn't want to make more changes than needed since I don't know rest of his code. Other than that, you're right.

Comment: @jfriend00 to be honest I didn't even thought about that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code example, is calling `fs.watch()` wrong.  You don't pass arguments to the callback yourself.  You just name parameters.

This program below all by itself works on Windows.  I pass it a directory and watch for changes to any of the files in that directory.  You can also pass it the filename for an existing file and watch for changes to just that file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.watch("./watcherDir", function(eventType, filename) {
    console.log(`eventType=${eventType}, filename=${filename}`);
});
```

`eventType` and `filename` are passed by `fs.watch()` to the callback, they are not something you pass.  You just create the name of the arguments that you can then use as function arguments inside the callback.

When I rename a file in that directory from `example.json` to `example.xxx`, I get these two callbacks:

```
eventType=rename, filename=example.json
eventType=rename, filename=example.xxx
```

The filenames are, of course, relative to the directory I passed to `fs.watch()`.

Note: As documented, this feature does not work the same on all platforms so for any further debugging we would need to know what platform you're running it on.